# Inserting specific symbols in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

I am making a batch file that inserts a string at the end of another batch file.

However, I would like to insert `%1` in the batch file. But `%1` is set to a value (command parameter) and thus, inserts the value of the parameter.

Command I am running:

```
floadd.bat test
```

Code that `floadd.bat` has inside:

```
( echo IF %1 ) >> flodo.bat
```

It inserts:

```
IF test
```

How do can I make it so that it will insert:

```
IF %1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `( echo IF %%1 ) >> flodo.bat`.

Comment: There will be a trailing space in the output; to avoid that use: `(echo IF %%1) >> flodo.bat`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Exactly what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add just a percent sign (`%`) to your code like this:

```
(echo IF %%1) >> flodo.bat
```

*Note: the space between the brackets and the code was removed. This is optional, just because these spaces add an extra space in your code.*